# Flex grid magic (CSS)

Tags: html, css, frameworks, grid

What kind of magic should I do to create [this](http://d.pr/i/Ex1p+) grid using "display: flex" rules?

Terms:

1. Resizable grid
2. Content of height is always 160px (for example)
3. Inside block: picture and text
4. Auto-width always, no fix at all

I have some good [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBtyr) — .col-auto style, but it needs to be in .row and it's not brake like on my picture.

Is there any CSS framework, that have such examples or in what way should I look for it?

Comment: Your best bet is to use media queries and specifically style the grid to look like each instance for a certain set of circumstances.

Comment: Since you tagged this w/ The adobe/Apache UI Framework [Flex[ is there a reason you aren't using the built in DataGrid?  Did you mistag this, or is there something else I don't understand?  For an HTML Grid; I would look to using a library [such as ngGrid or one of the many others out there; it will be lots more time effecient than trying to bulid a grid in scratch].

Comment: @Reboog711 Let me show, what I trying to do. [Click here](http://d.pr/i/rzK8+). DataGrid is not what i need.

Comment: Clearly, based on your two links you are not talking about Adobe/Apache Flex so I removed the Flex tag.  I'm not sure what the replacement would be.  Flexbox?

Comment: @Reboog711 I trying to do something like [this](http://shsh.me/flex/flex.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can use **.resizable();** function. Enable any DOM element to be resizable. With the cursor grab the right or bottom border and drag to the desired width or height.